# Handling null file from image_picker in image_cropper flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker, flutter-image, flutter-file

I'm trying to get an image using `image_picker` package and then passing to `image_cropper`. I have taken a bit different approach to avoid getting back to the home screen after image selection before going to crop image screen.

Here is my code for image selection and image crop.

```dart
Future<File> getImageFromGallery(BuildContext context) async{
    final File croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: File((await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)).path).path,
        maxWidth: 1080,
        maxHeight: 1080,
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0)
    );

    if (croppedImage  != null) {

      return croppedImage;
    }
    return null;
}
```

```
Error: The getter 'path' was called on null.
```

In tried `Null Safety`, but then it throws this error:

```
Failed assertion: line 81 pos 12: 'await File(sourcePath).exists()': is not true.
```

My code with Null Safety.

```dart
Future<File> getImageFromGallery(BuildContext context) async{

    final File croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: File((await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)).path).path,
        maxWidth: 1080,
        maxHeight: 1080,
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0)
    );

    if (croppedImage  != null) {

      return croppedImage;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please suggest me a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
final File croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
    sourcePath: img.path,
    maxWidth: 1080,
    maxHeight: 1080,
    aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1.0, ratioY: 1.0)
);
```

I think you should pick up the img first, check if it's valid img or not. And then pass the path to imageCropper.
So the code above should work fine..

Comment: I have tried this and it works perfectly fine with Gallery but for Camera there is a delay in capturing the image and taking the user to the crop image screen. That's why I choose the other way. I would be great it you could make that work.